# Unable to find modules required to enroll admin in Fabcar example - Hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am pretty new to Hyperledger fabric and StackOverflow as well. I was trying to experiment with the fabcar example - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html on Hyperledger. However, I am unable to proceed with enrolling the Admin.

After issuing

```
npm install
node enrollAdmin.js
```

in the fabcar/javascript directory, I am hitting the error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './utils.js'
Require stack:
- /b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAServices.js
- /b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/index.js
- /b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/enrollAdmin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAServices.js:10:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAServices.js',
    '/b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/index.js',
    '/b/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/enrollAdmin.js'
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure if this is some single sourcing problem between the fabric client and the fabric-ca-client. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs and npm. I have also tried pruning all the docker images, networks, volumes and start from scratch.

Here's the package.json for reference:

```
{
    "name": "fabcar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "FabCar application implemented in JavaScript",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8",
        "npm": ">=5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "pretest": "npm run lint",
        "test": "nyc mocha --recursive"
    },
    "engineStrict": true,
    "author": "Hyperledger",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "fabric-ca-client": "~1.4.0",
        "fabric-network": "~1.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "eslint": "^5.9.0",
        "mocha": "^5.2.0",
        "nyc": "^13.1.0",
        "sinon": "^7.1.1",
        "sinon-chai": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "nyc": {
        "exclude": [
            "coverage/**",
            "test/**"
        ],
        "reporter": [
            "text-summary",
            "html"
        ],
        "all": true,
        "check-coverage": true,
        "statements": 100,
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me find out what I might be missing here?

Environment details:

Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Node js version: v12.16.1

npm version: 6.13.4

Docker compose version: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe

Docker version: Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c

Fabric binaries: 1.4.0

Comment: There is a known issue, see https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1500

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right platform to search for fabric-sdk related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also faced this issue. And now I'm following this process to resolve.

**step:1** Check a fabric local version.I'm using 1.4.6.

**command:**

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.6 1.4.6 0.4.18
```

**step:2**

`cd fabric-samples/first-networks`

**step:3** To check this version is working or not.

```
./byfn.sh generate
```

**step:4**

```
 ./byfn.sh up
```

**step:5** Now down the network.

```
 ./byfn.sh down
```

After checking all the above process you can start `fabcar` project.

I successfully import my **admin** and **user1** identity.

Hope it will help you:)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the new "fabric-ca-client" package.Some minor updates changed the dependencies.
So, The working version is: `"fabric-ca-client": "1.4.0"`

I removed the tilde(~) to download the exact version.Rest of the dependencies and their versions are same.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That works well for enrolling the admin. I also hit the same issue in the next step when registering the user. I was able to resolve using the fabric-ca-client - 1.4.6.